# Android EditText value not showing up, getText returns a value

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext

Everything in my Activity is working fine.  I'm able to load all the values fine and show in every EditText except one.  The sequence of the actions on onCreate is

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rule_editor);
    initComponents(); //references all private objects to each object in activity layout 
    populateCategorySpinner(); //populates a category spinner
    loadRule(); //loads the rule from a singleton on the basis of an extra data passed from parent activity
    attachEvents(); //attaches event to each object
    Log.d("", txtIdentifierString.getText().toString());
}
```

The problem is in one of the EditText. The reference in code is txtIdentifierString.  The values that I set (by setText()) on it is not showing up in activity on runtime.

Logcat shows up a value from the Log.d method call in last line of the onCreate method, but its not visible in the EditText txtIdentifierString. The EditText box is visible, I can focus on it and type in a value as well.

Does anyone has any idea about it?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I have no idea what you're talking about or what the problem is.

Comment: maybe your edit text background color and text color might be the same which could make the text to be not visible properly.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some style applied that is causing your EditText's text color to be the same color as the its background?

Comment: Can you see cursor on EditText? Is it move as you type letters?

Comment: May be the problem is simply your TextColor . As I understood from your question

Comment: Ollie: I have elaborated it more

Andro: no, when I type something on it, its visible

Comment: dynmeh: Yeah I've made double checks about that
mahe: yeah I can see cursor and when I type, its visible

Comment: Just to debug, add: android:text="test" to the EditText in .xml.  Does that show up?

Comment: @Boswell it doesn't show up. I think something is resetting the value.  Does disabling and re-enabling cause this to happen?

Comment: Post more code.  Let's see what you're doing to that TextView.

Comment: @Boswell , thanks for your interest. I figured out a bug in my code and have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.
I debugged the codes and found out that `OnItemSelectedListener` on a spinner had to reset the EditText in question.  The change is triggered before I Logged the value